# If a set A has countably infinite members, why does it follow that the number of subsets of this set is uncountably infinite?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

If a set A has countably infinite members, why does it follow that the number of subsets of this set countably infinite?

My reasoning:
if the set A is countably infinite, there exists a bijection between it's members and the natural numbers. But the number of subsets of A, is much greater than the natural numbers( we can get the cardinality of A simply by counting the 1-element subsets, and informally if A had finite cardinality n, we know that it has 2^n subsets.).

is this enough to show the number of subsets is uncountably infinite?

Comment: Are you trying to show there are countably or uncountably many subsets?

Comment: What's the difference between showing the number of subsets is *greater than* the natural numbers vs. showing the number of subsets is *much greater than* the natural numbers? And how does an argument for sets with finite cardinality imply the analogous result for sets with infinite cardinality? If anything, one would think that very little can be carried over from finite sets to infinite sets in light of things like Hilbert's hotel.

Comment: No. This does not suffice. Rules for comparisons of "size" (cardinality) that work for finite sets do not generally apply to infinite sets.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's establish that there are uncountably many subsets of $A$.

> if the set A is countably infinite, there exists a bijection between it's members and the natural numbers.

So, let's enumerate $A$ as $A=\{a_0,a_1,a_2,\dots\}$.

Now assume (towards contradiction) that the set of subsets of $A$ is also countably infinite, then there exists a bijection between the subsets of $A$ and the natural numbers. Let's enumerate the subsets as $S_0,S_1,S_2,\dots$.

Now I define a subset $S$ of $A$ as follows: for every natural number $n$, let $a_n$ be an element of $S$ if and only if $a_n$ is not an element of $S_n$. Then $S\neq S_n$ for any $n$, since $a_n$ is either in $S$ or in $S_n$, but never in both. So since $S\neq S_n$ for all $n$, it was not included in our enumeration of subsets, thus this contradicts that there exists a bijection between the subsets of $A$ and the natural numbers.

---

Now let's see what is wrong about your line of thinking: if I understand correctly, you're saying that $A$ is in bijection with the $1$-element subsets, thus the number of subsets must be larger, since there are also many more subsets of $A$ with more than $1$ element.

By this argument, the set of all *finite* subsets of $A$ should also be uncountable, but this turns out to be false:

---

Let $X_n$ be the set of all subsets of $\{a_0,a_1,a_2,\dots,a_{n-1},a_n\}$ that contain $a_n$. If $S$ is a finite subset of $A$, then there is a largest $n$ such that $a_n$ is an element of $S$ (or $S$ is empty), so if $S$ is a finite subset of $A$, then $S$ is an element of $X_n$ for some $n$ (or $S$ is empty).

Then note that $X_n$ has size $2^n$: there are $2^n$ many subsets of $\{a_0,\dots,a_{n-1}\}$, and we can find a bijection between the subsets of $\{a_0,\dots,a_{n-1}\}$ and $X_n$ by sending $S\subset\{a_0,\dots,a_{n-1}\}$ to $S\cup\{a_n\}$. For each $n$, let's enumerate $X_n$ as $X_n=\{x_n^0,x_n^1,\dots,x_n^{2^n-1}\}$

Now let's enumerate all finite subsets of $A$. I set $S_0=\varnothing$, and $S_m=x_n^{k}$, where $n$ is the largest natural number such that $2^n\leq m$, and $k$ is such that $m=2^n+k$:

\begin{array}{llll}
S_0&S_1&S_2&S_3&S_4&S_5&S_6&S_7&S_8&S_9&\cdots\\
\varnothing&x_0^0&x_1^0&x_1^1&x_2^0&x_2^1&x_2^2&x_2^3&x_3^0&x_3^1&\cdots\\
\end{array}

This will enumerate all elements of all $X_n$ for any natural number $n$, and thus it enumerates all finite subsets of $A$. So there are only countably many finite subsets of $A$ (but by the same proof as in the start of my answer, there are uncountably many infinite subsets of $A$).

Answer (score 0):

The set of all subsets of a set $A$ is often denoted $P(A).$ The $P$ is for Power, as $2^A$ often denotes the set of all functions from $A$ to the two-member set $2=\{0,1\},$ and we can identify each $B\subseteq A$ with its "characteristic" ("indicator") function $\chi_B,$ where $\chi_B(y)=1$ if $y\in B$ and $\chi_B(y)=0$ if $y\in (A$ \ $B).$

One of the axioms of modern set theory is that the set $P(A)$ always exists.

Another axiom is Comprehension, wherein if $Q(x)$ is any property that any $x$ may or may not have, then for any set $A,$ the set $B=\{x\in A: Q(x)\}$ exists. This is actually an endless list of axioms (an axiom schema), one axiom for each property $Q$ that you can name or write.

Georg Cantor, the founder of set theory, proved the following:

Theorem: For any set $A$ and any function $f:A\to P(A),$ there exists $B\in P(A)$ such that $B\ne f(y)$ for any $y\in A.$

Proof: By Comprehension let $B=\{x\in A: x\not\in f(x)\}.$ Now suppose  $B=f(y).$ Then

(i). $y\in B$ implies $y\not\in f(y)$ (by definition of $B$), which implies $y\not\in B.$

(ii). $y\not\in B$ implies $y\in f(y)$ (by definition of $B$), which implies $y\in B.$

So in either (i) or (ii) we have a paradox, so no such $y$ can exist.